# Chord averaging of scattering experiment on a cylinder

Tags: numerical-integration, fitting, averages

In a scattering experiment in transmission, a cylinder is scanned from side to side (x position from -R to +R). Therefore, chords of length 2*Sqrt(R^2-x^2) are intersected.
The property of interest varies inside the cylinder and depends only on the radius, P=P(r) and is averaged by the experiment on the chord that is intersected. 
Assuming that P(r) can be described by:

```
P[r] := a + b E^(c r);
```

where a,b,c are parameters.

the chord average of P(r) leads to:

```
Pmeas[x0_?NumericQ, a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ, c_?NumericQ]:=1/Sqrt[R^2 - x^2]*NIntegrate[(r*P[r])/Sqrt[r^2 - x^2], {r, x, R}]
```

this is what is actually measured by the experiment.
If I assume some values for the parameters, I can readily plot P[r] and Pmeas[x,a,b,c]. Eg:

```
Show[ Plot[Pmeas[x, 0.24, 0.0017, 0.13], {x, 0, R},PlotRange -> {{0, R}, {0, 0.5}}],Plot[P[x] /. {{a -> 0.24, b -> 0.0017, c -> 0.13}}, {x, 0, R},PlotStyle -> Red]]
```

So, the direct problem is readily possible.

In reality however, the inverse problem is more interesting as Pmeas(x) can be measured and P(r) is what I am interested in. 
In other words: I am measuring Pmeas and I would like to fit the parameters (a,b,c) that characterize P(r). So what I do is:

```
data = {{0.75`, 0.2500216473070521`}, {1.75`, 
0.24997855408403824`}, {2.75`, 0.24989220143397992`}, {3.75`, 
0.24973952669238306`}, {4.75`, 0.24950568454019323`}, {5.75`, 
0.249185001971573`}, {6.75`, 0.24878177549110536`}, {7.75`, 
0.24831088729457407`}, {8.75`, 0.24779821718747438`}, {9.75`, 
0.24728082699540485`}, {10.75`, 0.24680689422049204`}, {11.75`, 
0.24643537169800125`}, {12.75`, 0.2462353500072835`}, {13.75`, 
0.24628509939121196`}, {14.75`, 0.24667076793825868`}, {15.75`, 
0.24748471278136458`}, {16.75`, 0.2488234410677535`}, {17.75`, 
0.25078513745384284`}, {18.75`, 0.2534667548794025`}, {19.75`, 
0.2569606453751139`}, {20.75`, 0.2613507076576813`}, {21.75`, 
0.2667080282666464`}, {22.75`, 0.27308599299705955`}, {23.75`, 
0.2805148453821578`}, {24.75`, 0.2889956689802035`}, {25.75`, 
0.298493770219633`}, {26.75`, 0.3089314385566694`}, {27.75`, 
0.32018006069955096`}, {28.75`, 0.33205156565352517`}, {29.75`, 
0.3442891773407628`}, {30.75`, 0.3565574515493425`}, {31.75`, 
0.3684315739654576`}, {32.75`, 0.3793858960429981`}, {33.75`, 
0.38878168546465847`}}; R = Max[data[[All, 1]]];

P[r_] := a + b E^(c x);

Pmeas[x_?NumericQ, a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ, c_?NumericQ]:= 1/Sqrt[R^2 - x^2]*NIntegrate[(r*(a + b E^(c r)))/Sqrt[r^2 - x^2], {r, x, R}]

FindFit[data, Pmeas[x, a, b, c], {{a, 0.24}, {b, 0.0017}, {c, 0.13}},x]
```

but I only get errors from FindFit and no values for the parameters {a,b,c}. Eg:

```
Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0. encountered. >>
```

Can anybody help?

Comment: You're dividing by zero when `x = Max[data[[All,1]]] == R`.  Adding a small amount to `R` will allow `FindFit` to complete without error but it might not make any sense in terms of the model.

Comment: actually this works!

Comment: It does "work" in that `FindFit` completes without error.  But does it make sense to do so?  Certainly, the estimates of `a`, `b`, and `c` change with the amount that one adds.  Is there some theoretical value that `R` should take rather than relying on the maximum value in the data?

Comment: nope. R has geometrical meaning: radius of the cylinder that is under investigation. The values of a, b and c are not so affected by adding a small amount to R (I did a small sensitivity analysis). So: I can live with this work-around. But indeed this is just a work-around.

Comment: Is this the question I was discussing  and commenting yesterday ???

Comment: yes. I posed it in a more structured way here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments, adding a small amount to `R = Max[data[[All,1]]]` allows `FindFit` to complete without error as otherwise division by zero occurred.

I suggest avoiding `FindFit` and using `NonlinearModelFit` because one can obtain much more than the estimates of the coefficients such as the residuals, the estimated variance and covariance of the coefficient estimators, confidence bands, etc.

The fit does not look very good in that there is a lot of structure that remains.  Also, a simpler looking model with just as many coefficients provides almost identical estimates:

```
(* Original model *)
R = Max[data[[All, 1]]] + 0.01;
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, {Pmeas[x, a, b, c]}, {{a, 0.24}, {b, 0.0017}, {c, 0.13}}, x];

(* Exponential model *)
nlm2 = NonlinearModelFit[data, a + b Exp[c x], {{a, 0.23}, b, c}, x];

Show[
 Plot[{nlm[x], nlm2[x]}, {x, 0, 34}, 
  PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0.2, 0.42}},
  PlotStyle -> {{Thickness[0.02], LightGray}, Red}, 
  PlotLegends -> {"Pmeas", "Exponential"}],
 ListPlot[data]]
```

[image: Comparison of fits]

The predicted/residual plot shows that there is still a lot of structure to explain:

```
ListPlot[Transpose[{nlm["PredictedResponse"], nlm["FitResiduals"]}],
 Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"Predicted value", "Residual"}]
```

[image: Predicted vs residual plot]

Is this remaining structure related to a wrong theoretical construct or is the measurement device that produced the data not cooperating with the theory?

Comment: good suggestion to use NonlinearModelFit. With respect to the residuals, I believe that this is the effect of the 'non-ideality' of the system. Actually, the object that I am working with is close (but not exactly) a cylinder and the property P(r) could also deviate from a pure function of the radius.